# How to render modules in prestashop template?

Tags: templates, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Please explain me, how to display some module in my prestashop template, especially list of categories and menu. I can't figure out, i tried to render some hook but no result...

Answer (score 0):

Beside render the hook in the template file, you also have to transplant the module to the correct hook in "Modules > Positions".